# Курсор на границах элемента

Tags: html, css

Делаю возможность изменения размера элемента с помощью мыши. Как сделать так, чтобы курсор при наведении на границу элемента становился типа `resize`?

Желательно, чтобы направление ресайзера соответствовало тому, над какой конкретно границей курсор.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Границы делать отдельными блоками.

Answer (score 1):

Это надо реализовывать с помощью CSS а "границы" сделать из DIV.Я сейчас делаю свой API: [WebWinAPI](http://www.webwinapi.16mb.com) там это как раз реализовано (подведите мышь к границе окна)